# Server authentication connection in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, owin, xamarin.forms

I have a Azure web server that i want to connect to using user name / password.

The server authentication is OWIN.

I also want to send a file after connection using POST.

If I need a token how do i obtain it ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the technology you are using (asp, mvc)? And any infos on the clients that are going to connect to the application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some information.  Do you want to connect to a Web API that's hosted on an Azure Web Server?

You can use Azure AD for authentication.  There's a lot of information about Azure AD and various set ups here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios